# In the Jenkins email-ext plugin, how do I specify the arguments (the regex and the new output) to the ${LOG_REGEX} token?

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

The Jenkins email-ext plugin supports a `${LOG_REGEX}` 'token'. It's documented like this:

> ${LOG_REGEX}
>
> Uses a regular expression to find a single log entry and generates a new output using the capture groups from it. This is partially based on the description-setter plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/description-setter-plugin).

(That's part of the documentation that's shown when I click on the "?" (question mark) associated with the Content Token Reference in the Editable Email Notification section of the Jenkins project configuration page.)

When I use this token, how do I specify the regular expression and the output? I guess it probably takes a pair of parameters, but, if so, what are their names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined through trial and error that the parameter names are `regex` and `replacement`.

For example, if your job console contains

> Started by upstream project "my-project" build number 12345

then the token

```
${LOG_REGEX, regex="^Started by upstream project \"(.+)\" build number ([0-9]+)", replacement="\\1 #\\2"}
```

will be replaced by

> my-project #12345

Keep in mind that, in parameter values, `\` and `"` must be escaped with a `\`.